# Raspberry Pi 4 B unmounting and mouting intermittently

Tags: raspbian, pi-4, usb-power, hard-drive, mount

I had two drives on my Raspberry Pi 4 B and they kept being unmounted, I moved one to my router and it seems to be working fine now...
I read about `max_usb_current=1` doesn't make any difference on Raspberry Pi 4 B, but is there any chance I could put lots of drives on my Raspberry Pi and have them stable? I'm using the official power supply.

Comment: Read [this bit on powered hubs](https://elinux.org/RPi_Powered_USB_Hubs).

Comment: Like @Seamus said, try to use a powered hub. Make sure it's been tried before as I've had trouble with a couple myself

Comment: You can't run two usb powered drives on an Rpi 4. The current limit is 1.2 A shared between all USB ports, and one drive alone will take up to 1 A on spinup and maybe on seek, so you do the arithmetic. I tried 2 drives and got the same thing, and then I read the spec.

Answer (score 1):

As others suggested, the problem was that there wasn´t enough power to feed 2 hard drives, so using a usb-hub with power adapter solved the issue